# ssh -f, running remote startkde, does not exit. Why?

Tags: shell, ssh, kde

I hope that someone already knows the answer to this, because I fear that trying to unravel the startkde shell script, and the subtleties of `ssh -f` is going to be ugly.

I am opening a remote desktop  on a centos 7.2 server running KDE 4.14.8, from a cygwin shell with Cygwin ssh version OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015.

I start my local XWin server, then run

```
ssh -fXY myself@centhost /bin/startkde > /tmp/kde_out.txt 2> /tmp/kde_err.txt
```

This "works", but ssh never returns. I log out from kde, and the XWin display goes black, but then it seems to hang. When I look in my /tmp/kde_err.txt file, I see the lines

```
...
startkde: Shutting down...
klauncher: Exiting on signal 15
klauncher: Exiting on signal 1
startkde: Running shutdown scripts...
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
startkde: Done.
```

but ssh is never exiting. Also, my XWin server does not close automatically, and when I close it manually, it complains that there are still 6 clients connected. BTW, I get the same hang without stdout and stderr redirection of ssh.
The startkde script is version 4.11.19, and it is sh, not bash. The last line of the script is `echo 'startkde: Done.'  1>&2` but there is one `trap 'echo GOT SIGHUP' HUP` command early in the script. [Here is a link to the whole script.](https://gist.github.com/Charlweed/14b1b0cb0c29e85bfc81)

Is this hang more likely due to the startkde script, the side-effects of the kde executables, or some known ssh client-server behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: no. It does not work like this. You can forward windows over ssh, but not the whole desktop environment. It was discussed many times here.